# Get All "Drafts" in Content View

Tags: 8, views, workflows

In essence, I'm trying to make a view of the moderation state "Drafts", (using Content Moderation).

The catch, I'm trying to do so in a *Content* view for maintainability purposes.

However, it won't show content that has been set the "Published", then back to "Draft". (Because the default revision is still "Published".)

I've played around with the "Content Revisions" relationships, but no success.

Comment: Are you using the content moderation module? That creates a default view for this I believe under "/admin/content/moderated" that might be able to help you work out what to do if you dont want to just use that view

Comment: @LeighMason Yes, I am. I did end up going that route, exporting my view display then reimporting with config dependencies and relationship: nid. However, I would have to manually edit it every time I edit the base view, causing me to still want to a solution...